# SQL Server Stored Procedure Ejecución en PHP

Tags: php, sql-server

Que tal a  todos los que lean esto. 
Tengo una consulta que llevo como dos días intentando saber que es y no doy con que pueda ser.
Utilizo un Stored Procedure en SQL Server para varios scripts de PHP.
La cuestión es que a veces se hace la ejecución del SP correctamente y algunas otras digamos que lo ejecuta, pero no me devuelve resultados. Al checar lo que sucede al momento de ejecutar el SP del resultado me devuelve resource(14) of type (SQL Server Statement) y al consultar con sqlsrv_num_rows me devuleve int(0), lo cual quiere decir que está ejecutando el SP pero no devuelve nada aunque al ejecutar manualmente si me de resultados. ¿Qué podrá ser? Se me ocurría que pudiera ser el tiempo de ejecución del SP pero realmente no tengo seguro nada.

```
    CREATE procedure [dbo].[sp_Sel_CFD_Generados_Dia]  
   @Inicio varchar(10),      
   @Fin    varchar(10)      
 as      
   select isnull(B.Owner,0) as 'Owner', isnull(B.ProyectoId,0) as 'ProyectoId',     
          isnull(D.Xref,'') as 'Xref',  isnull(B.IdNoSocio,0)  as 'IdNoSocio',      
          A.Origen, A.CFDSerie, A.CFDFolio,       
          'Compañia' = case when A.CompanyKey = 'OHFP'     
                            then 'TGM'     
                            else A.CompanyKey     
                       end,     
          A.DocumentEffect as 'Tipo',      
          '\XML\' + ltrim(rtrim(A.ArchivoPDF)) as 'ArchivoPDF',     
          '\XML\' + ltrim(rtrim(A.ArchivoXML)) as 'ArchivoXML',      
          A.InvoiceDate as 'FechaFactura', B.IdPromesa as 'Folio',       
          'Mail1' = case when isnull(B.Owner,0) <> 0     then isnull(D.Email,'')      
                         when isnull(B.IdNoSocio,0) <> 0 then isnull(C.Email,'')      
                    end,      
          'Mail2' = case when isnull(B.Owner,0) <> 0     then isnull(D.Email2,'')      
                         when isnull(B.IdNoSocio,0) <> 0 then isnull(C.Email2,'')      
                    end,      
          'Movimineto' = case when E.Movimiento like '%Mantenimiento%'     
                                   then 'Mantenimiento ' + convert(varchar(4),MesAño)      
                              when E.Movimiento like '%Mensualidad%'     
                                   then 'Mensualidad ' + convert(varchar(4),MesAño) + '/' + convert(varchar(4),[Meses Finan])       
                              else E.Movimiento      
                         end,      
          B.Moneda, B.Importe, D.Pais,
          'Lada1' = case when isnull(B.Owner,0) <> 0     then isnull(D.LadaCelular,'')      
                         when isnull(B.IdNoSocio,0) <> 0 then isnull(C.LadaCelular,'')      
                    end,      
          'Celular1' = case when isnull(B.Owner,0) <> 0     then isnull(D.TelefonoCelular,'')      
                         when isnull(B.IdNoSocio,0) <> 0 then isnull(C.TelefonoCelular,'')      
                    end,      
          'Lada2' = case when isnull(B.Owner,0) <> 0     then isnull(D.LadaCelular2,'')      
                         when isnull(B.IdNoSocio,0) <> 0 then isnull(C.LadaCelular2,'')      
                    end,      
          'Celular2' = case when isnull(B.Owner,0) <> 0     then isnull(D.TelefonoCelular2,'')      
                         when isnull(B.IdNoSocio,0) <> 0 then isnull(C.TelefonoCelular2,'')      
                    end
          from tbl_Cat_CFD_Repositorio A      
          left join tbl_Cat_Recibos_Cabecera_Historico B on A.DocumentNo = convert(varchar(25),B.IdRecibo)      
          left join tbl_Datos_Generales_No_Socios C      on C.IdNoSocio = B.IdNoSocio and B.IdNoSocio <> 0      
          left join tbl_Datos_Generales_Socios D         on D.Owner = B.Owner and D.ProyectoId =B.ProyectoId and B.Owner <> 0      
          left join tbl_Cat_promesas_Pago E              on B.IdPromesa = E.IdPromesa      
          /*where isnull(A.EnvioMail, 'N') = 'N'
            and A.InvoiceDate > '01/04/2018'*/


      where InvoiceDate >= @Inicio + ' 00:00'     
        and InvoiceDate <= @Fin    + ' 23:59'      
        and not E.Movimiento like '%Monto%Cuenta%'      
        and not E.Movimiento like '%Reactivacion%Contrato%'      
        and not B.Importe = 0      
        and D.Pais like '%mex%'      
        and ((not B.Importe > '50000' and B.Moneda = 'MN' or not B.Importe > '5000' and B.Moneda = 'USD'))      
        and not isnull(B.IdNoSocio,0) in ( 608890, 614933, 614982, 616189, 616190, 616191, 616192, 616193, 616194, 616195 )     
        and not isnull(B.[Owner],0) in ( 70613, 70614 )     
        and A.Estatus = 'A'  
        and isnull(A.EnvioMail, 'N') != 'S'
      order by FechaFactura
```

Código php:

```
    $fecha = date('m/d/Y', strtotime('-1 days'));
$sql    = "EXEC sp_Sel_CFD_Generados_Dia @Inicio = ?, @Fin = ?";
$result = sqlsrv_query($mssql_link, $sql, array($fecha, $fecha), array('Scrollable' => 'static'));
if ((bool) $result === false) {
    file_put_contents(LOG_FILE, '[' . date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . '] OCURRIO UN ERROR AL EXTRAER LOS DATOS' . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
    foreach ($errors = sqlsrv_errors() as $error) {
        file_put_contents(LOG_FILE, '[' . date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . '] SQLSTATE: ' . $error['SQLSTATE'] . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
        file_put_contents(LOG_FILE, '[' . date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . '] code: ' . $error['code'] . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
        file_put_contents(LOG_FILE, '[' . date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . '] message: ' . $error['message'] . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
    }
```

Comment: Creo que sería más útil si compartes el código que estás usando. Tanto el de PHP como el del SP.

Comment: acabo de actualizar mi pregunta con el código que estoy usando

Answer (score 0):

Depende de la versión de sqlsrv, pero proba agregar lo siguiente al inicio de SP.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
```

En algunos casos muy puntuales un PRINT dentro de SP puede generar problemas, también ten en cuenta que si el SP devuelve más de un recordset, debes usar la función **sqlsrv_next_result** para pasar al siguiente conjunto de resultados, por ejemplo:

```
$result = array();

do {
   while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query)) {
       $result[] = $row;
   }
} while (sqlsrv_next_result($query));

print_r($result);
```

Comment: Utilizo PHP 7 y el server es ubuntu 18.04.1. Ya intenté agregando SET NOCOUNT ON; al SP pero sigue sin devolverme resultados, aunque lo ejecuta de manera correcta. Esto de no devolver nada solo pasa ciertas veces. No pasa siempre.

Answer (score -1):

Prueba lo siguiente:

**-** El servidor puede que tenga un tiempo maximo de ejecución. Al ser a traves de PHP puede que demore un poco mas.

**-** Suele pasar (o por lo menos con Python) si el SP retorna algun SELECT en medio puede detectar que es el final del SP y termina la ejecución.

Seria bueno que nos muestre algún ejemplo o parte del código para saber mejor que es lo que esta sucediendo.

Comment: Efectivamente el SP retorna SELECT de varias columnas, lo que se me hace extraño es que con los scripts que uso ese SP hay días en que funcionan sin problema y otros en que me devuelve 0 registros si se ejecuta desde script. Pero no me arroja error de tiempo de ejecución por parte del servidor

Comment: No tienes el log de errores de PHP? Es posible que los SP se detengan a mitad del proceso por algun error en una consulta dentro. Tienes un Handler de errores dentro del SP que te muestre si hay errores?

Comment: Tengo solo el log de PHP, pero solo tiene errores... Nomales. Warnings, Notices de cuando intenta utilizar los datos que devuelve el SP.

Comment: Es posible ver ambos codigos? De los SP y PHP

Comment: Ya actualicé la pregunta e incluí los códigos